# Adding Windows 7 VHD back to multiboot in Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, backup, multi-boot, vhd

I have currently installed Windows 8 Pro with WMC on my laptop.

This laptop came with Windows 7, here were some stock apps installed by HP that I want to run now, unfortunately, HP has not yet supported Windows 8 for a few apps, on the official websites they say, it works only with Windows 7, I still tried installing them but they actually dint work.

When I got this laptop, I made a bootable VHD backup of the installation, so I have the stock Windows 7 install with me. Now, the problem, I tried adding this VHD to the bootloader, as soon as I do this, I loose Windows 8 bootloader (and I cant boot into Windows 8), it loads Windows 7 but later crashes in the start progress only. This VHD worked before perfectly. I recovered the current bootloader with "Repair" options.

How can I add Windows 7 VHD back to the bootloader without loosing Windows 8?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that happen? Just try to add the VHD with `bcdedit`.

Comment: As I mentioned before, it seems like as soon as I add the VHD, it does not gives and option to load Windows 8. Also it crashes at the time of loading, the windows logo formation.

Comment: I am trying to install Windows 7 over Windows 8 using VHD. And still trying to figure out the whole process using Internet resources. Were you successful in this? Were you able to sort this problem out? Can you guide me in in some way? Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to do this, and I left it thereafter. Though, I have something in my mind now. You can add the VHD to bootloader and make it default using `msconfig`, then run the Windows 7 Boot Recovery mode to fix all bootloader errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to do this (free only for personal, non-commercial use). Install and open the application and go to "Add new entry". In the lower pane select the "Virtual disk" tab, enter the name and path of the VHD, then just click "Add entry".

Comment: I dont think that you read the question properly, I stated that when I add the VHD to the bootloader, I loose Windows 8 as an option, it loads Windows 7 directly and also it dosent boot up correctly (crashes with a BSOD at loading - at the windows logo formation).

Comment: I understood your question, but I thought you added the VHD to the bootloader with `bcdboot` or some other tool than EasyBCD.

Comment: Will that actually make any difference?

Comment: I haven't tried this with VHD images, but with Linux bootloader entries and Chameleon, modifying the BCD was more successful with this than with other tools.

Comment: Add Linux bootloader has some different steps than adding a Windows installation, automated tool like this can so it much better than the manual ways (mostly). But when adding Windows to the Windows bootloader itself, the process is same for manual or automatic method. It would just differ with small little steps.

One thing I could see that, adding a older version of windows to a newer version like in this case is always a problem. The bootloader of the older version interferes with the newer one, but the new one knows how to load the older one.